# Isolated storage and cache memory in wp7

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have read a lot and bit confused that isolated storage and cache memory are different..is it right or can anyone explain me or give a link to know the exact difference or its the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'cache memory' in Windows Phone 7. Isolated Storage allows you to store data as key/value pairs, files and folder or in a database, as detailed in the [overview found in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28VS.92%29.aspx). It is 'isolated' in the sense that this storage is not shared between applications.

Your reference to 'cache memory' might be bitmap caching? This is a technique that Silverlight uses to cache rendered regions on the screen. See this SO question:

[BitmapCache? When and how to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716473/bitmapcache-when-and-how-to-use)

Comment: I have downloaded 200 images from a URL and stored in isolated storage when the application is started..Shall i retrieve the images from that storage while in offline...is it permanent once i stored the data in iso store..

Comment: It depends on what settings you use. One more thing, it is not persistent in emulators but it is persistent in WP(once again the settings matters!)