# What is BitmapCache in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, bitmapcache

I already read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716473/bitmapcache-when-and-how-to-use), but I don't figure out what `BitmapCache` does.

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967560%28v=VS.92%29.aspx),

> Bitmap caching allows visual elements to be stored as bitmaps after
>   the first render pass. After the element is cached, the application
>   bypasses the render phase for the cached visual element and displays
>   the stored bitmap instead.

I set `CacheMode="BitmapCache"` for my `ListBox`. I think that after the 1st render, the OS will save its visual as a bitmap, then continue to show that bitmap in each frame, without render it again. I think the `ListBox` should be static now. But I can still scrolling the `Listbox`.

I must understand it wrong. Please explain what `BitmapCache` does ?

If it is good, why don't we set `BitmapCache` for every element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the ListBox should be static now. But I can still scrolling the Listbox.

When you scroll the listbox, it redraws its content, thus updating the cached representation. The bitmap cache is useful for some transformations, like a translation. In those cases, the cached representation has many advantages:

1. The control doesn't have to redraw its content => CPU economy
2. Since the visual representation isn't dependent of the control anymore, it can be handled directly by the GPU

> If it is good, why don't we set BitmapCache for every element ?

BitmapCache uses more memory, and it seems there's corner cases where it can actually have a negative performance impact (though I'm not knowledgeable enough on the subject to enumerate them). A good way to know if BitmapCache should be turned on is to set the `EnableRedrawRegions` setting to true. The emulator will then show which areas are redrawn, and you can set the BitmapCache accordingly.